# Refactor without using 3 connections and commands in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql, .net-6.0

I have 3 queries, so I opened 3 connections and created 3 lists `allTransactionLists`, `incomeLists` and `expenseLists` to make an object if getting data from rows.

Instead, can I have only one connection and execute 3 queries at the same time?

I am using NPGsql and ado.net here in this ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC.

Can anyone help me?

```
public IActionResult AllTransactionsList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var dataset = new DataSet();

    using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection.Open();

    using var connection1 = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection1.Open();

    using var connection2 = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection2.Open();

    Console.WriteLine(startDate);

    /* query to account name, type, date, amount note from transactions and account table based on transaction_id */
    var query = String.Format(@"SELECT a.account_name, a.type, DATE(t.date), t.transaction_id, t.amount, t.note 
                                FROM transaction AS t
                                INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id
                                WHERE t.date BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}' 
                                ORDER BY t.date;", startDate, endDate);

    /* query to calculate sum of all rows in amount column from transaction table* of type="income" */
    var incomeQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS income, a.type 
                                      FROM transaction AS t
                                      INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                      WHERE a.type = 'income'
                                        AND t.date BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}' 
                                      GROUP BY a.type", startDate, endDate);

        /* query to calculate sum of all rows in amount column from transaction table type="expense" */
        var expenseQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS expense, a.type
                                           FROM transaction AS t
                                           INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id
                                           WHERE a.type = 'expense'
                                             AND t.date BETWEEN '{0}' and '{1}'
                                           GROUP BY a.type", startDate, endDate);


        using var sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        List<Transaction> allTransactionLists = new List<Transaction>();

        using var incomeSqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(incomeQuery, connection1);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader2 = incomeSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        List<Transaction> incomeLists = new List<Transaction>();

        using var expenseSqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(expenseQuery, connection2);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader3 = expenseSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        List<Transaction> expenseLists = new List<Transaction>();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                allTransactionLists.Add(new Transaction
                    {
                        TransactionId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["transaction_id"]),
                        AccountName = Convert.ToString(reader["account_name"]),
                        Type = Convert.ToString(reader["type"]),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]),
                        Amount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["amount"]),
                    });

                }
            }

            // to calculate income
            if (reader2.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    incomeLists.Add(new Transaction
                    {
                        Income = Convert.ToInt32(reader2["income"]),
                    });
                }
            }

            // To calculate expense
            if (reader3.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader3.Read())
                {
                    expenseLists.Add(new Transaction
                    {
                        Expense = Convert.ToInt32(reader3["expense"]),
                    });
                }
            }

            var model = new AllTransactionViewModel();
            model.AllTransactions = allTransactionLists;
            model.IncomeLists = incomeLists;
            model.ExpenseLists = expenseLists;

            return View(model);
        }
}
```

Comment: not sure about postgre, in sql server you have [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15). Maybe you have a similar thing in postgre

Comment: I just had a quick look at your SQL queries... Why don't you just query once the database? your `FROM` and `WHERE` are identical in the three queries

Comment: The 3 commands don't seem to have any dependency between them. So I'd strongly suggest batching them together in a single roundtrip, and then going over the 3 resultsets of the command. The code above does three roundtrips to the database (and uses three physical connections...) which is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I see many things in your code, so I will answer with a list.
First, go to the business:

1. Your first query return a list of transactions, so is not related directly to the other query, but the other 2 query as related.
2. Your query 2 and 3, never ever will response a list of items, always the response will be only one register. Because your filter for one condition is related with the field of grouping. This affect your model, and your code,
3. Related with previos point, so, you can put the query 2 and 3 in only one query.

```
SELECT 
  a.type,
  SUM(t.amount) AS amount,  
FROM 
  transaction AS t INNER JOIN account AS a 
    ON t.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE 
  a.type in ('expense', 'income')
  AND t.date BETWEEN '{0}' and '{1}'
GROUP BY 
  a.type
```

| type | amount |
| --- | --- |
| expense | 20000 |
| income | 15000 |

But on this point i don't know if maybe you want the expense and income grouping by account id, is not clear on your queries.

Related with code.

1.- Use only one connection object, try to use with a  singleton pattern.

2.- Puth the code inside of Using section, to ensure the use of disposable related with connection.

3.- Change your model, because on this point the value of expense and income is not a list.

4.- Later of that and when your code work, try to separate the logic of database from the controller.

I hope my comments can help you